# Error during installation gem 5 in full system mode

Tags: command-line, system-installation, system

On giving the command below in gem5 directory

```
**build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/pradnya/full_system_images/aarch-system-2014-10/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img** 
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Feb 17 2015 18:02:39
gem5 started Apr  4 2015 11:06:36
gem5 executing on ubuntu
command line: build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/pradnya/full_system_images/aarch-system-2014-10/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img
Traceback (most recent call last):
  **File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pradnya/gem5/src/python/m5/main.py", line 388, in main
    exec filecode in scope
  File "configs/example/fs.py", line 326, in <module>
    test_sys = build_test_system(np)
  File "configs/example/fs.py", line 101, in build_test_system
    cmdline=cmdline)
  File "/home/pradnya/gem5/configs/common/FSConfig.py", line 272, in makeArmSystem
    self.kernel = binary('vmlinux.aarch32.ll_20131205.0-gem5')
  File "/home/pradnya/gem5/configs/common/SysPaths.py", line 49, in binary
    return searchpath(binary.path, filename)
  File "/home/pradnya/gem5/configs/common/SysPaths.py", line 41, in searchpath
    raise IOError, "Can't find file '%s' on path." % filename
IOError: Can't find file 'vmlinux.aarch32.ll_20131205.0-gem5' on path**
```

I am getting the error above. please help me with it

Answer (score 1):

Please set your `M5_PATH` environment variable using the following command:

```
echo "export M5_PATH=/path/to/full_system_for_gem­5/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This is also explained here: http://wikiankita.blogspot.com/2017/11/installation-of-gem5-simulator-for-fs.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that M5_PATH is not needed anymore as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319473/gem-5-ioerror-cant-find-a-path-to-system-files-full-system-x86-simulation-set you can just point to your kernel explicitly which is much saner.

A highly automated setup that takes care of everything for you can also be found at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8a5c310535ffa86acfa93b4e9de13858ebc709ee#gem5-arm